# Tifr gs 2023 question about sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{ n \to \infty} (x_{2n-1}+x_{2n})=2$ and $\lim_{ n \to \infty} (x_{2n}+x_{2n+1})=3$ then what will be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{2n+1}}{x_{2n}}$?

My attempt: $\{x_n\}$ can't be convergent otherwise the two limits should be equal. I was thinking to do $\lim_{ n \to \infty} (x_{2n-1}+x_{2n}+x_{2n+1})$ and compute it two different ways but I can't as the sequence is not convergent. I need some hint where to start form.

Comment: Formatting note:  using \lim looks better.  And \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}  gets you the arrow underneath the limit, as in $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$, if you prefer that.

Comment: I use \lim\limits_{x\to 0} to format, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$

Comment: Thank you @lulu

Comment: Subtract the limits to get $\lim_n(x_{2n+1}-x_{2n-1})=1$. You can also change variable $n\to n+1$ in the first, before subtracting to get $x_{2n+2}-x_{2n}\to-1$. So, $x_{2n+1}\to +\infty$ and $x_{2n}\to-\infty$. Use [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_*/%E2%88%9E_case) to finish.

Comment: Got it, thanks@NDB